# how can i launch chrome using selenium webdriver in Java not as a guest but as my chrome profile?

Tags: python, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm sorry, in Java, I want to load a page with Chrome browser through Selenium web driver, but when I do this, Chrome enters with profile as guest. But I want to enter the Chrome browser through the profiles I had installed before and I have a Google account. I looked for all the answers on the stackoveflow site and did them all, but none of them worked. For example, one of these is

```js
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("user-data dir=C:\\Users\\Remi\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Profile 1");

options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 1");

options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I'm really tired, I gave up and ran the program. Please, a hero, answer me and solve my problem. i worked on this one week but nothing happend and chrome still pop up as a guest i am really tried

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this approach, and it is working for me. Before running the program, you should close the current Chrome browser**

```
package selenium1Basics;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class BaseTests{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 4");
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.testassist.dev/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='button-7 w-button']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using another automation lib and development tool, but it only support python now, not like selenium webdriver way, it can operate the user's browser, for your question, it's easy to do it in the following way:

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.bing.com", userdata_folder_mode='custom', userdata_folder_path="C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 19")
```